# Package that is similar to R's caret?

Tags: r

Recently I stumbled upon a R package that works similar like caret, but I can't remember what it's name was and I can't find it. It seemed to be less well known, but at least as extensive. Someone able to help?

**Edit:** I search for this other package to widen my horizon. There is no specific other reason. This question is specific however, since I am not looking for a general recommendation, but I am looking for this specific package I have in mind. I will recognize the package once I read its functions and descriptions. I had searched for a couple of hours myself and did not find it by searching for "package similar to caret". That is why I need help.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36505537/4993513) is closed for a reason.

Comment: @Dawny33: I would love to know what the reason is. That is something I really hate about SE: Downvotes and closes without good reason. **This is not about a recommendation.**

Comment: I understand that it is frustrating. But, this qn **is a recommendation**, as it does not have necessary details. It isn't clear why would you want another package similar to `caret` when there's caret?

Comment: @Dawny33: I edited my qn accordingly ;-). Giving an answer and being helpful wasn't actually that hard as it seems...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**MLR** is similar to **caret**, MLR offers a high-level interface to various statistical and machine learning packages.

According to the package description:

> Interface to a large number of classification and regression
>   techniques, including machine-readable parameter descriptions. There
>   is also an experimental extension for survival analysis, clustering
>   and general, example-specific cost-sensitive learning. Generic
>   resampling, including cross-validation, bootstrapping and subsampling.
>   Hyperparameter tuning with modern optimization techniques, for single-
>   and multi-objective problems. Filter and wrapper methods for feature
>   selection. Extension of basic learners with additional operations
>   common in machine learning, also allowing for easy nested resampling.
>   Most operations can be parallelized.

Please check the [Reference](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlr/index.html) and [Homepage](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/).

Comment: Yeah, I think this was the one.

Comment: I do not dare to ask... but do you have a recommendation :-D in comparing those two? I haven't found anything useful on the net so far. Which one is more comprehensive and intuitive in the long run (not necessarily "how fast can I learn it") in practical data science tasks? (This site is about practical data science, as far as I know.)

Comment: @Make42 Caught you asking for recommendations again :P. Btw, I would vote for `caret` just due to the number of contributors and the number of users using the package. I haven't used it personally, however, MLR seems to be boasting more functionalities than `caret`.

Comment: I also vote for caret package.